# Freemaker Template Dynamic Data Lists

Tags: liferay-6

In my Freemaker Template I like to call

```
<#assign formDDMTemplateId = GetterUtil.getLong((String)row.getParameter("formDDMTemplateId"))>
```

therefore I need to import the class GetterUtil:

```
<#assign GetterUtil = serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil")>
```

If I do so I get the following error:

```
serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil") is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to GetterUtil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to portal-ext.properties this:

```
freemarker.engine.restricted.classes=
freemarker.engine.restricted.variables=
```

and you don't have to assign GetterUtil.

Answer (score 0):

GetterUtil is class. You can assign like:

```
<#assign GetterUtil = staticUtil["com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil"]>
```